# Excel automatically adding an extra row with formulas for the inputed number of years

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I am looking to build a model. I would like to have an input page where you input the range of years you would like to cover.  Depending on the inputted number of years, I want a table (on a different worksheet) to be populated with the existing formulas.

To be more specific, I have a table full of formulas that has a row for each year, ranging from 2005-2014.
My request is as follows:

Is there a way to make an input page that takes in the years and change the table and add/subtract rows based on the inputted range?  For example, we change the range on the input page to 2005-2018, then my table will add 4 more rows with the equations.

Comment: you can either use a macro to do this or formulas copied down more rows then you need that are =if(sheet1!a1="","",your formula here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution**
To automate this, use some VBA code that resizes your table after updating the start and end years.

**The code**
Here is my implementation of this, with the years in "Sheet1" (cells B1 and B2) and the table in "Sheet2". Note that you *must* add this code to the sheet where the years are in, because the code has to run whenever you change something on that sheet. So in my case, this code is added to "Sheet1".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim StartYear, EndYour As Range
    Dim UpdateTable As ListObject
    Dim NrOfRows, OldNrOfRows As Integer

    ' Set some ranges
    Set StartYear = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2)
    Set EndYear = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2)
    Set UpdateTable = Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table1")

    ' Check if start or end years have changed
    If (Not Intersect(StartYear, Target) Is Nothing) Or (Not Intersect(EndYear, Target) Is Nothing) Then
        ' Store the new and old number of rows
        OldNrOfRows = UpdateTable.ListRows.Count - 1
        NrOfRows = EndYear.Value - StartYear.Value + 1

        ' Resize the table
        UpdateTable.Resize UpdateTable.Range.Resize(1 + NrOfRows)

        'Delete cells below the table if it gets smaller
        If OldNrOfRows > NrOfRows Then
            UpdateTable.Range.Offset(NrOfRows + 1, 0).Resize(OldNrOfRows - NrOfRows + 1).Delete
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**Some points of explanation of the code**
Some references to Microsoft functions/methods/properties to explain the code:

- Excel can call a sub [whenever a value on a cell is changed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775(v=office.15).aspx). That sub is called `Worksheet_change` and the cell that is changed is given as a range value.
- I use the [Intersect function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835030(v=office.15).aspx) to check if the cells which contain the start/end year have changed. The NOT-NOTHING construction may make it a bit harder to read, but the effect is that the `IF` is entered if NOT-NOTHING is changed.
- To resize the table, I use the [Resize method of the ListObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838369(v=office.15).aspx) (which requires a range object) and the [Resize methode of the range object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193274(v=office.15).aspx) (which requires one or two int's).
- Finally, if the table gets smaller, I had to manually delete the contents below the new table. Here again I use some nested [range offset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060(v=office.15).aspx) and [range resize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193274(v=office.15).aspx) functions to [delete the right range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834641(v=office.15).aspx).

Comment: I have been out of the office and have not been able to try this.  How do i update the table to apply all functions to be carried over.  
I put a simple table in sheet2 and provided it with the name "Table1" but once i change the EndYear, I received an errer to debug the coding. Is there any way you can explain further?

Many thanks in advance!

Sam

Comment: So I got that equation to work only if I select the table area and press on "Insert Table' once provide with the table name I include it in the macro. But it did not work if I simply name the table. Also another qustion, Is there a way to do a loop to update table1, table2, table3?

Thanks!!

Comment: @Sam: what have you tried yourself? SU is no software factory. Try to look at Microsoft's help sites on VBA. A [FOR-EACH-NEXT loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) should do it. You'll never learn if you don't try it yourself.

Comment: @Sam: it is considered polite to mark your question as "accepted" if the answer works for you...

Comment: my appologize!  I have this position temerary for now until mid november I become full time.  Therefore I only have access to the files one day a week which is friday.  In all honesety I wrote a loop and got most of it to work, but apparently it never saved.  I will attemp to redo the loop today and run it by you for advice.

Comment: I have a big worksheet i'm working on but trying to give an example on a smaller scale. 

Apparently i can't upload all code because its too large.  I add loop and it seems to work on multiple tables.  The problem i encounter is that with your coding it is adding and deleting a line from the positive end of the table!  What I mean by the positive end is that its deleting or adding years from the bottom.  How do i change that and delte/add column from the top of the table?

My orignal years were 2007-2014, new table 2005 - 2014, how to get to add/delete the original years as well?